# VBA Code for Finding Cells Below which match the key

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following requirement I have 2 columns with unique keys called code. In one column below the code, there are one or multiple values present which is the answer. Like in below format

A X
1
2
B Y
9
3

Now the code will have a value populated in next column, while answers wont.

Now I have to find answers for all codes like A, B, C etc. For e.g If I compare with A then answer should be 1,2. I was writing a small subroutine as a beginning but I am facing issues. Can you please correct it

```
Sub CalculateCellValue()
Dim ValuesBelow As Variant
Dim ValuesRight As String
Dim rows1 As Integer
rows1 = 4
Dim colC As Integer
colC = 2
ValuesRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows1 + 1, colC + 1)

While (Not IsEmpty(ValuesRight))
 ValuesBelow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows1 + 1, colC)
 rows1 = rows1 + 1
 ValuesRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows1 + 1, colC + 1)
Wend
MsgBox (ValuesBelow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue you are seeing? Are you not getting anything returned in your MsgBox, an error, ...?

Comment: I am getting error "Run time Error 6" for the line "ValuesRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows1 + 1, colC + 1)"

Comment: The Run Time Error is because your code reaches the limit of the spreadsheet and tries to keep going. The `Not IsEmpty(ValuesRight))` condition never triggers as True since `IsEmpty` only tells you if a variable has been given an initial value, which it has from the beginning. I can also tell you that you'll run into other issues, so you should take a look at QHarr's answer below for a good solution. 

Here's more detail about the `IsEmpty` function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isempty-function

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my mistake and below code works fine for me. Though may not be the perfect one.

Answer (score 1):

Purely for an ordered example as shown:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5")             'Change as appropriate

    Dim myArr()

    myArr = ws.Range("A1:B" & GetLastRow(ws, 1)).Value

    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)

        If myArr(i, 2) <> vbNullString Then

            If Not dict.exists(myArr(i, 1)) Then
                Dim currKey As String
                currKey = myArr(i, 1)
                dict.Add myArr(i, 1), vbNullString
            End If

        Else

            dict(currKey) = dict(currKey) & ", " & myArr(i, 1)

        End If

    Next i

    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In dict
        MsgBox key & " = " & Right$(dict(key), Len(dict(key)) - 1)
    Next key

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    With ws

        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to match my requirement

```
Function findBelowAll(rows1 As Long)

Dim ValuesBelow() As Variant
ReDim ValuesBelow(1 To 1) As Variant
Dim ValuesRight As Variant
Dim colC As Long
colC = 1
Dim i As Long

ValuesRight = ""

While (ValuesRight = "")
rows1 = rows1 + 1
' change / adjust the size of array
    ReDim Preserve ValuesBelow(1 To UBound(ValuesBelow) + 1) As Variant

    ' add value on the end of the array
    ValuesBelow(UBound(ValuesBelow)) = 
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(rows1, colC).Value

ValuesRight = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(rows1, 2).Value
Wend

For i = LBound(ValuesBelow) To UBound(ValuesBelow) - 1
    findBelowAll = findBelowAll & ValuesBelow(i) & vbNewLine
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I was trying to add values to the valuesbelow variant. So that I can pass that in result. It was throwing me some errors till I gave redim.Is it possible to do without redim ?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Can you give an example?

Comment: And apologies, you are preserving because you are in a loop which I couldn't see. Indenting your code properly helps others read you code. As ReDim Preserve makes copies of the existing array you generally want to oversize in advance and use a counter to then ReDim at end, or if size known in advance, just size appropriately straight away.